# How to install SQL * PLUS client in linux

Tags: linux, oracle, amazon-ec2, centos, sqlplus

I am working on AWS services. I have an `ec2 ( centos )` instance. I need to configure SQL*Plus client on this centos machine.

The server with whom I want to connect is at some remote area. The server version is `oracle-se(11.2.0.2)`

How can I get the client installed on the CentOS machine?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Go to [**Oracle Linux x86-64 instant clients**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html) download page

Download the matching client

```
oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.2.0.x86_64.rpm
oracle-instantclient11.2-sqlplus-11.2.0.2.0.x86_64.rpm
```

Install

```
rpm -ivh oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.2.0.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh oracle-instantclient11.2-sqlplus-11.2.0.2.0.x86_64.rpm
```

Set environment variables in your `~/.bash_profile`

```
ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
export ORACLE_HOME
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH
```

Reload your `.bash_profile` by simply typing `source ~/.bash_profile` (suggested by jbass) or Log-out user and log-in again.

Now you're ready to use SQL*Plus and connect your server. Type in :

```
sqlplus "username/pass@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.2.1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=YOURSID)))"
```

Comment: Hi I have installed it now when I am trying to connect to the server it is givig me an error : `-bash: sqlplus: command not found`

Comment: Okay i added the `export ORACLE_SID= "oracledb"

export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/

export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH` in bash_prfile. Now when I try to connect it gives me error: `sqlplus: error while loading shared libraries: libsqlplus.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: @MeghaSharma try setting env variable `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib`

Comment: @MeghaSharma Pls refer the updated answer. Thank you.

Comment: I have done everything but now getting this error :`ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`

Comment: @MeghaSharma can you show how you're trying to connect to SQL*Plus? Your whole sqplus command

Comment: `sqlplus "rdsuser@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=oracledbrds.abcdefg.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA(SID=oracledb)))"` the oracle server is residing on AWS RDS instance.

Comment: Its done. there was an error in the command. was giving double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: Do we need to set `NS_ADMIN` and how to import dump to the server. Kindly check my question and please help m eout

Comment: I cant find the TNSNAMES.ORA in the home directory of oracle

Comment: Please help, I think so the instant client don't have all the packages the bin folder has `adrci  genezi  sqlplus`

Comment: the admin/network directory is also not there. Also the bin dir contains only adrci  genezi  sqlplus. I am not able to import the dump

Comment: @MeghaSharma Under your $ORACLE_HOME (after setting up .bash_profile properly), create these directories: `mkdir -p $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin` (Also, it should be network/admin, not admin/network). Then create `tnsnames.ora` file under `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin`, and add your tns entries in it. That worked for me.

Comment: the sqlplus package does not install because the dependency to the basic package cannot be resolved ?!? this didnt seem to be an issue back then.

Answer (score 6):

The solution by @ChamaraKeragala is good, but it is unnecessary to logout/login. Instead type:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: this should not be an answer but a comment, also is already integrated in the @ChamaraKeragala aswer ( accepted )

Comment: @Thomas8 It was added as an edit in ChamaraKeragala answer after jbass answer (it's specified in the answer as a thanks to).

Answer (score 2):

For everyone still getting the following error:

> sqlplus command not found

The original post refers to a set of environment variables, the most important of which is `ORACLE_HOME`. This is the parent directory where the oracle binaries get installed.

Depending on what version of oracle you downloaded you'll have to change the `ORACLE_HOME` accordingly. For example, the original question's `ORACLE_HOME` was set to:

```
ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
```

My version of Oracle happens to be 12.1, so my `ORACLE_HOME` is set to:

```
ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64
```

If you are unsure of the version that you downloaded, you can:

1. `cd /usr/lib/oracle` after the installation and find the version.
2. Look at the RPM file oracle-instantclient**12.1**, where the bolded bits would refer to the version number.

Answer (score 2):

There's a good blog post[1] on $subject. setup oracle client in ubuntu with minimum effort. Following are the main steps on how to step up the client.
In my case, I was installing rpm files using alien package.

1. Install alien and related packages

   `sudo apt-get install alien`
2. Install oracle client packages using alien.

   `sudo alien -i oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.3.0-1.x86_64.rpm`

   `sudo alien -i oracle-instantclient11.2-sqlplus-11.2.0.3.0-1.x86_64.rpm`

In my opinion these two steps are the easiest way to install oracle client rpm's on your ubuntu system. (I'm not going to mention about export oracle specific variables as it's already clearly explained in above answers)

Hope it helps someone.

[1] http://pumuduruhunage.blogspot.com/2016/04/setup-oracle-sql-plus-client-on-aws.html

Comment: Do you still have to manually download the .rpm files in advance? As I got this error: "File "oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm" not found."

Comment: Yes you need to download the rpm manually

Answer (score 0):

For any one who is using proxy, you'd need to add an extra line to the bash profile. At least this is what made it work for me. I'm using cntlm.

export no_proxy=

Answer (score 0):

**Install via zip (tried with 12_2)**

<strike>First of all there is no need to set `ORACLE_HOME`.</strike>

Simply download the `.zip` files from [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html) starting with the first one `Basic:` followed by `SQL*Plus:` and any additional zips you may need.

Extract them all under `/opt/oracle`

You will then have a directory: `/opt/oracle/instantclient_x_y`

On ubuntu I had to do also:

```sh
sudo apt install libaio1
```

To run:

```sh
# This can be also done by adding only the path below in: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_x_y:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# This can be added in ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/instantclient_x_y
/opt/oracle/instantclient_x_y/sqlplus user/pass@hostname:1521/sidorservicename
```

At the bottom of the the above link page there are more details.