# -bash: imp: command not found oracle

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, bash, oracle11g

I have a `centos Linux` machine and a `oracle server` installed on a server which is located at a remote location.

I have installed `oracle client` on my Linux centos machine using the link :

[How to install SQL * PLUS client in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488394/how-to-install-sql-plus-client-in-linux)

It may be noted that while installing client there was no `/network/admin` directory and hence no `tnsnames.ora` file. now I have manually created the directories and have have created a tnsnames.ora file. I am able to connect to remote server.

Now when I look into the bin folder I get just three exe

```
 adrci  genezi  sqlplus.
```

I cant find the imp.

Hence when I try to import the dump file from centos to oracle , I get the error:

```
-bash: imp: command not found
```

I am using the following command to import dump on oracle server:

```
imp 'rdsuser@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=oracledbrds.cwuabchlhlu.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DAT                                                                                        A(SID=oracledb)))'
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

The instant client does not include many of the tools from the full client, including `imp`/`exp`, their newer data pump equivalents, SQL*Loader etc. [See the instant client FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/oci/ic-faq-094177.html), which highlights that it's largely for distribution with your own applications, but can incude SQL*Plus - the only tool mentioned.

If you need to use export/import or any other tools then you will need to install the full client, or run them on the server; which might be an issue with AWS. [Amazon have an article on importing data into Oracle](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html).

Incidentally, you can put your `tnsnames.ora` file anywhere as long as you set `TNS_ADMIN` to point to that location, but you aren't referring to it in your `imp` command anyway - you're specifying all the connection data. If you know the service name, which may be different to the SID (you can run `lsnrctl services` on the server to find the right value) you can use the 'easy connect' syntax:

```
sqlplus rdsuser@//oracledbrds.cwuabchlhlu.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:1521/your_service_name
```

Comment: How can I install the full oracle client or the imp/exp utilities

Comment: You can get the express edition [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html), or the standard/enterprise editions [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html) - you can get just the client from the 'See All' link next to your platform, for 11g or 12c. You need to think about licensing though, depending on what you're doing. The installation instructions vary for the version and platform and you can get those from the same links.

Comment: Where did your dump file come from - can you transfer the data directly from the original database to AWS (see the doc link I added to the answer)? Or can you use the `imp` tool on the server you exported from, if you're stuck with the legacy export rather than data pump?

Comment: I cannot directly import the database to oracle rds, I have to use some utilities. Please help.

Comment: The oracle server version is 11.2

Comment: Could you please explain the steps to install the oracle client properly

Comment: @MeghaSharma - did you look at [the importing guide link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html)? I'm slightly confused, is your DB on the same EC2 server, or on a separate server - I assume it's somewhere else or you could use the server's own `imp` without needing a separate client installation. Otherwise [this](http://cloudconclave.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/importing-on-premise-oracle-database.html) *might* be useful, but not something I've used.

Comment: The ec2 server has the oracle client and the RDS server is different. I can connect to RDS using Oracle client only. Kindy help

Comment: There is [a whole section in the Oracle documentation about installing the client](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e47959/toc.htm).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52279/discussion-between-megha-sharma-and-alex-poole)