# to establish database connection using UNIX shell script

Tags: oracle, shell, unix

I am new to shell scripting and have less or no idea on this.
I have to read a db.properties file which has the database connection details i.e. to which db to connect. Then i have to establish a connection to that database and perform an operation to check the current time.

Below is my db.properties file :-

```
driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@171.01.187.94:1532:DEV
userName=abc
password=abc
```

Below is my script to call the db.properties file :-

```
#!/bin/bash

file="./database.properties"

if [ -f "$file" ]
then
    echo "$file found."
 . $file

  echo "User Id       = " ${userName}
  echo "user password = " ${password}
  echo "url  = " ${url}

  sqlplus -S ${userName}/${password}@${url}

else
    echo "$file not found."
fi
```

But i am getting the below error :-

ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Could anyone please help on the above issue ?

Comment: Your local TNS setup for Oracle doesn't include the database you want to connect to.  You include a Java JDBC driver class name, but you use sqlplus client. Seems off to me.

Comment: @duffymo :- yes it is not :( 
could you please help me modify the script as per my requirement ?

Comment: No, contact your Oracle database admin.

Comment: You don't pass a JDBC URL to `SQL*Plus`.  That's never going to work.  You'd generally want to create an entry in your `tnsnames.ora` file, assuming that you are using local naming, that points to this database.  Assuming that TNS alias is named "dev", you'd then `sqlplus user/password@dev` to connect to the database.

Comment: See the Answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23534668/bash-imp-command-not-found-oracle for more (but incomplete) info on tnsnames.ora. Good luck.

Comment: @justin cave i replaced the url in db.properties file with DEV and it got connected as below :-
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't worry about tnsnames.ora definition, you have all information needed to establish a connection using sqlnet.

Modify your database.properties file as follows:

```
driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
url='(description=(address_list=(address=(protocol=TCP)(host=171.01.187.94)(port=1532)))(connect_data=(service_name=DEV)))'
userName=abc
password=abc
```

And that's it. You don't need to change your script.

```
#!/bin/bash

file="./database.properties"

if [ -f "$file" ]
then
    echo "$file found."
 . $file

  echo "User Id       = " ${userName}
  echo "user password = " ${password}
  echo "url  = " ${url}

sqlplus -S ${userName}/${password}@${url}

else
    echo "$file not found."
fi
```

Note: I assumed that DEV is the database service name, if it's the database SID just modify configuration string as:

```
driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
url='(description=(address_list=(address=(protocol=TCP)(host=171.01.187.94)(port=1532)))(connect_data=(sid=DEV)))'
userName=abc
password=abc
```

Regards

Comment: I have added the below in my script
#!/bin/bash

file="./database.properties"
query="SELECT SYSDATE -2 FROM DUAL"

if [ -f "$file" ]
then
    echo "$file found."
 . $file

  echo "User Id       = " ${userName}
  echo "user password = " ${password}
  echo "url  = " ${url}
  
  sqlplus ${userName}/${password}@${url}
  <<EOFSQL
  $query;
  EOFSQL

  
else
    echo "$file not found."
fi

Answer (score 0):

please try / in between port and SID name.
username/password@host:port/SID