# sqlplus remote connection giving ORA-21561

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have installed sqlplus based on instruction given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23488394/how-to-install-sql-plus-client-in-linux)

```
sqlplus 'username/password@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.100)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ORCL)))'
```

This is giving me error

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Fri Jul 10 16:10:38 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-21561: OID generation failed


Enter user-name:
```

What is the solution for this problem?

PS: I have already added hostname and hosts have already have value.

Comment: This is very likely an `/etc/hosts` issue. First, are you using the XE version of Oracle? Second, do you have a line in `/etc/hosts` for 192.168.0.100 with the correct fully-qualified host name specified? In other words, if `hostname` returns `my-pretty-computer` when executed on the computer where the Oracle instance is running, execute `nslookup "my-pretty-computer"` - this will return the fully-qualified host name.

Comment: I am not using XE. Where should i run nslookup from 192.168.0.100 machine or at the localmachine?

Comment: Assuming your network is configured properly it shouldn't matter where you run `nslookup`. You might try running it both places just to make sure you get the same response! :-)

Comment: nslookup "my-pretty-computer"
Server:  8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find my-pretty-computer: NXDOMAIN

Comment: thats from oracle machine

Comment: nslookup "my-pretty-computer"
Server:  192.168.0.21
Address: 192.168.0.21#53

** server can't find my-pretty-computer: SERVFAIL

Comment: thats from client machine

Comment: Instead of "my-pretty-computer" you need to put in the name of the computer where the Oracle instance is running. Go to that computer and type `hostname`, then use the name that's returned in the `nslookup` command. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82937/discussion-between-neolivz4ever-and-bob-jarvis).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Append the name of your server to the hosts file.

If your /etc/hosts file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain
```

It should be changed to:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain hostname
```

hostname can be obtained from the command "hostname".

Comment: I found this also solved the issue even though my server was on a remote system and not local.

Comment: Can anybody explain why it helps? It did work for me, but I am using AWS machine where I can't make these changes easily on "elastic" events. Is there another way to accomplish the same thing? Perhaps setting some environment variable?

Comment: Works for me even when my Oracle database is located in a remote machine.

Answer (score 17):

If you are using Mac add local computer name to your 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts

It will be like

```
127.0.0.1       localhost <local_computer_name>
```

Way to find local computer name

System Preferences>Sharing(search for it if you cant find)
on the top you can see your local computer name

or you can use "hostname" command to get local computer name

Comment: Looks like a common problem for mac. Helped me to connect to docker oracle container

Answer (score 0):

This issue can also be cause by wrong permissions on the `/etc/hosts` file. If it is not readable for the Oracle uid, the errors will show.

Make sure your /etc/hosts is readable by everybody:

```
$ ls -l /etc/hosts
-rw-r--r--    1 root     system        7446 Mar 28 23:03 /etc/hosts 
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer obtained [here](http://chaos667.tumblr.com/post/20006357466/ora-21561-and-oracle-instant-client-112).

1 - Get your hostname:

$ hostname

*new-host*

**2 - Change the contents of /etc/hosts:**

$ sudo cat /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain

::1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

$ sudo nano /etc/hosts

$ sudo cat /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1 localhost *new-host*

::1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

**Hope this helps (:**

Answer (score 0):

look at /etc/sysconfig/network 
change if needed the hostname

Answer (score -1):

try this, don't put single quotes

```
sqlplus username/password@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.100)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ORCL)))
```

Comment: try like this once   dbvar="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.100)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ORCL)))"

sqlplus username/password@$dbvar

Comment: Same error. 
ERROR:
ORA-21561: OID generation failed

Comment: See the content in your host file /etc/hosts there should be entry for this IP.

Comment: 127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.0.100  MYORACLE
~                                                                                                                                                                                                           
~