# TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified from on remote Linux machine

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle11g

I am facing this error TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified while trying to connect to Oracle DB from linux remote machine.

I saw lot of posts on the same , but not helped so starting a new thread.

**Details**

I have a linux on VirtualBox and Oracle DB on VMWare Fusion. Both are installed on Mac El-capitan.

I am able to connect to Oracle DB using sqlplus command with oracle client 12.1.0.2. But not from Linux.

**Settings configured**

As per suggestions on all other posts, I have covered all the settings:

1. Hostname of oracle DB on Linux VM.
2. Setting ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_SID to DB name.
3. Checking listener configuration.
4. Connection (ping/telnet) to Oracle DB.
5. Test connection using sqlplus command from Linux VM.

My `tnsnames.ora`:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File:

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XXX.YYY.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

AAA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XXX.YYY.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

`sqlplus` connection from Mac - Successful Attempt

```
Tests-MacBook-Pro:~ test$ /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1/sqlplus abc/abc@XXX.YYY.com:1521/XE

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Thu Oct 6 13:43:52 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
```

`sqlplus` connection from Linux - UnSuccessful Attempt

```
[sushil@linux test-linux-setup]$ /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1/sqlplus abc/abc@XXX.YYY.com:1521

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Tue Oct 4 22:37:00 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-21561: OID generation failed


Enter user-name: ***
Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified


Enter user-name: ***
Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified


SP2-0157: unable to CONNECT to ORACLE after 3 attempts, exiting SQL*Plus
```

Telnet connection on 1521 port from linux

```
sushil@linux test-linux-setup]$ telnet XXX.YYY.com 1521
Trying 192.168.34.128...
Connected to XXX.YYY.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]q

telnet> q
Connection closed.
```

Could anyone shed a light on why this is happening?

Comment: I am using Oracle DB on Centos 7.

Comment: It might help if you edit the question to show how you are trying to connect - the exact command and connection string you use, for both the successful and unsuccessful attempts. And if you're using a TNS alias, your `tnsnames.ora` entry.

Comment: @AlexPoole, I have added tnsname.ora entry with commands I used from connection Oracle DB.

Comment: Your Linux command doesn't have the `/XE` on the end? (You aren't actually using the `tnsnames.ora` for either connection here)

Comment: You are also looking at the wrong error - you're ignoring the [ORA-21561: OID generation failed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31338916/266304).

Comment: Actually I do not have any idea why its coming as I am able to telnet to Oracle DB on 1521. I have already went through posts for ORA-21561: OID generation failed.

Comment: To improve your chances, I edited your title to a round question - if it doesn't match your intent, feel free to fix it.