# python cx_Oracle connect Remote error

Tags: python, oracle

i would like to connect to remote `oracle database` with python and try to create a pandas dataframe:

```
con = ora.connect('user/pass@remote_ip/XE')
query = "select * from my_table"

df = pd.read_sql(query, con)
```

I'm using macOS high siera and this is how my host file looks like:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost local
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain local lynx
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1     activate.adobe.com
127.0.0.1     practivate.adobe.com
127.0.0.1     hlrcv.stage.adobe.com
127.0.0.1     na1r.services.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 quickplayer.tvgo.hu
80.211.194.173 anton
10.2.94.217 lynx
```

I got `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-21561: OID generation failed` error.

If i try from Ubuntu it's working.

My Database version:

```
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
CORE     11.2.0.2.0            Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
```

What should I try?

Comment: Updated my question with the database verison, and it's not on the same machine where the macOS is running. Database is on Ubuntu machine.

Comment: This is how my host file looks like: 127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain 10.2.94.217 lynx because my oracle server ip is 10.2.94.217  and the host name the ubuntu machine that running oracle server is lynx. Still not working. :(

Comment: What do you get when you type `hostname` in your Mac terminal?

Comment: QGMAC:~ gabor_dev$ hostname
QGMAC.local

Comment: Add that hostname after the `127.0.0.1` then try again.

Comment: this is how my host looks like now: 127.0.0.1 QGMAC.locall localhost localhost.localdomain 10.2.94.217 lynx still not workin..

Comment: you're missing the port after the hostname, it should be like:
username/password@hostname:port/service_name

Comment: i've changed my connection string in my python code: 'user/pass@10.2.94.217:1521/XE' and the same error occured.

Comment: Does your hosts file have QGMAC.locall instead of QGMAC.local? Maybe that is a typo and it should be QGMAC.local.

Comment: :) it was that! :) please write an answer and i will accept it. Thank you! :)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338916/sqlplus-remote-connection-giving-ora-21561 which also provides the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary of the comments:

Run hostname to get what your OS thinks your name is.

In this case hostname returned QGMAC.local

Add this line to your hosts file:

127.0.0.1 QGMAC.local

From Don Burleson's site:

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_21561_oid_generation_failed.htm

"...the problem is most likely in the client machine hosts file.  Check that there is client machine fully qualified name and short name in the client machine hosts file."